# How to calculate the distance between vertices couples and show it as text

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I wish to create a function using geometry nodes that calculates the distance between consecutive vertices of a mesh, and adds text depicting the calculated distance between each pair of vertices, exactly at the center of the segment they form. I imagine I need to convert the mesh into a curve first, use the 'Geometry Proximity' node somehow, and also use the 'Value to String' and 'String to Curve' nodes... But this should be done in a loop, probably using fields, for every pair of vertex. I'm not sure how to proceed, normally I would include an example file, but I haven't been able to put together anything that makes sense. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can be optimised a bit if we only use the 11 needed base instances (meaning number from 0 to 9 and the dot).

The principle is the same:

Calculate edge lengths.

Iterate over the edges and sample lengths and positions.

Place instances calculated from the length at the edge position.

[image]

Now instances are first made from the "0123456789." text.

Its an iteration again, over the given text so that we create one text curve per character.

[image]

Then, another iteration from the length converted to text in order to associate the length text from the instances created above.

[image]

Result on a subdivided Suzanne:

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: +1 really nicer solution!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciated the feature that makes the text size proportional to the edge lengths, moreover, it was my intention to include it from the beginning but I did not specify it to avoid unnecessarily complicating the question and to get straight to the point. This was exactly what I needed. I was surprised to see how using more nodes makes the node tree more efficient; I would have expected the opposite, although I understand that this approach in the algorithm allows for saving on processing

Answer (score 3):

with this node setup:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

> Note: Try this out with a simple geometry. It is for sure not the
> fastest solution, so for suzanne it can take a while

> Note2: I recommend using a vertex group or another limiting factor so
> that you show only "a few" distances for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I manually recreated your node tree to learn and to better understand @lemon modifications. It worked perfectly, but when I tried the optimized solution from lemon I saw how much faster it is on my computer, and I am going to accept his answer because of this. Thanks very much for your time and for what you teached me and everyone